# How can I give my release/debug EXEs different names

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In VC++ I'm used to naming my debug EXE with the suffix "_d" e.g MyApp_d.exe. In C# I can't see where I can set the application binary name on a per-configuration basis. Is it possible?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093338/vs2008-outputting-a-different-file-name-for-debug-release-configurations

That may be able to help you.

Comment: Although the question is tagged VS2008 the duplicate still works fine in 2013